# Why does Java compiler work so fast?

Tags: java

I have small code. I don't know why Java compiler work so fast.

This is code:

```
int a= 0;
    while(true) {
        a++;
        if(a==0) break;
    }
    System.out.println(a);
```

And if I put `println` in while-loop it print line by line slowly.

```
int a= 0;
    while(true) {
        a++;
        if(a==0) break;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

And my question is: How does the mechanism of Java makes it work so fast (in example 1)?

Comment: In 2nd example, JVM has to print information to standard output which is another resource, which makes it slow compared to first example where there is single call to output resource at end.

Comment: One is doing extra work by printing to the console, and the other is not. Obviously the one doing less work runs faster.

Comment: @NguyenCongTri Are you interested in the time spent *compiling* or *running*? The title says one thing and the question an other.

Comment: it's my fault I'm so sorry @Biffen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.out.println is very slow compared to a purely computational while. The first example just hits the break and println is called once, while your second example has a println in every cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In both the cases the compiler takes the same time to check the conditions, but in example 1 you have written an extra line and you have to print something on the console.
System.out.println is an expensive operation.
Its System.out.println statement taking time not for checking the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to the console is expensive and displaying it is even more expensive.  Every system call is about 1000x more expensive than an operation lie `a++` and actually updating the screen is > 10x more expensive again.

A loop which doesn't do anything can be discarded by the JIT.